# (Micro) USB Timed Relay

Tags: usb, timer

I am currently trying to build a low power server with a Raspberry Pi I don't use any more (3B) but I am struggling to find a way to cut down it's power usage in it's off hours. Since the Pi uses ~100mA even when completely shut down, I am looking for a way to terminate the power going to it until such time as it needs to be booted back up for use. The server itself is intended to be outside my control for long (a month or more preferably) periods of time so anything that requires I be there isn't applicable.

Basically, I am looking for some kind of device or module that uses a very low amount of power, 5mA or less (preferably MUCH less), with micro-usb slots that either has a timer or can be programmed with a timer that will power off one of the slots after a certain time period and then turn it back on at another.

Below is a crude representation of what I am looking for.
[image: Crude picture of what I am looking for]

The only thing I have found that even comes close is the Sleepy Pi [(One example of where it's sold)](https://www.tindie.com/products/Fuffkin/sleepy-pi-2-intelligent-battery-power-for-rpi/). However I really don't want to shell out $50+ for something that should be much easier to accomplish if I can avoid it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want some form of "Real Time Clock"
Web searching RTC and/or "Real Time Clock" will show you much.

I'm advised that the RPM has no low power sleep mode.
While you cannot enable an internal micropower Pi RTC mode you WILL be able to have it woken (or turned on) periodically, allowing it to check if it wants to be awake and, if not, again turning itself off **completely.**  A simple hardware counter and power up circuit could draw under 1 microamp and wake the system hourly or daily or ... . A more intelligent system (as simple as eg an Arduino or an RTC IC) would allow you to set the "delay time to next wakeup".

You could (with certainty) use an eg Arduino with wake up / alarm capability to restart the Pi. With due care (app notes available) current drain can be half an oily rag (ie under 10 uA with eae and under 1 uA with a little more effort.)
[A 100 mAh LiIon single cell will provide 10 uA for over a year].

There are numerous RTC ICs available.
Some will have "alarms" (interrupt drives or switched turn on, or ... for Pi).

Asian suppliers on AliExpress sell many RTC modules with a range of capabilities. Prices start from about $0.00 ish.

You COULD use a classic low power counter and power up and have the Pi check time etc and resleep if desired. The effort and cost would be higher than alternatives.

---

**Ultra low power Arduino:**

Here is how to operate an Arduino Pro-Mini (the Pro being an inexplicable but irrelevant label) at about 5 uA in sleep mode but WITH the watchdog timer running.

[ARDUINO LOW POWER - HOW TO RUN ATMEGA328P FOR A YEAR ON COIN CELL BATTERY](http://www.home-automation-community.com/arduino-low-power-how-to-run-atmega328p-for-a-year-on-coin-cell-battery/)

He makes use of [this](https://github.com/rocketscream/Low-Power) excellent low-power Arduino library to achieve various low power modes.

Pro-Minis are available for $2 (or less) from China.

Aliexpress [Arduino Real Time Clock](https://www.aliexpress.com/wholesale?catId=0&initiative_id=SB_20191117194828&isPremium=y&SearchText=arduino+real+time+clock) - cveat emptor, as ever, but most probably OK.

---

Various RTC modules from Digikey [here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/development-boards-kits-programmers/evaluation-and-demonstration-boards-and-kits/787?k=real%20time%20clock)
 and [here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/development-boards-kits-programmers/evaluation-and-demonstration-boards-and-kits/787?k=ds1307)

RTC 1307 'Hats' / modules ... intended for various systems

[here](https://www.digikey.com/products/en/development-boards-kits-programmers/evaluation-boards-expansion-boards-daughter-cards/797?k=ds1307)

---

**Olde Technology - CD4060 self oscillating divider:**

It's been quote some decades since I've used these - but I think a wakeup oscillator with a current in the 1 - 5 uA region should be possible.

[CD4060](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4060b.pdf) - Digikey $US0.53/1.
Needs 2 resistors and a acapacitor to operate.
IC quiescent is 5 uA max, 40 nanoamp typical (! :-) ) at 5V.
Add oscillator current of Vcc/Rtiming - say maybe 1 uA or less, and the oscillatior gate may draw more in the transition region depending on how good a job they did.

See fig 12 for circuit.

Comment: Nope, the pi has no real power management or low power modes.  That and the SD card basically ruin it for embedded usage.

Comment: @ChrisStratton OK. Thanks. So everything after the introduction applies :-). I should edit it to As ... .

Comment: As this is the most comprehensive answer, and the road I decided to take, I've marked it the answer. However, I chose these route due mainly to monetary constraints. I feel the need to make that clear.

Comment: @anonymousman21 As I proposed 3 methods I don't know your route. AND don't feel obliged to accept my answer. As long as you accept one all is well. I din't need the rep (any more than I need the unclear clarification :-) )

Answer (score 0):

Look at using a low power MCU that actually does have suspend modes as a supervisor to decide when to restart the pi, and have it switch power to the pi via something like an RT9742 or similar USB downstream power switch chip.

Although RT9742's aren't ultra low quiescent current, they are in the microamp range and should meet your need.  Or you may be able to find something better.

Beware the temptation to use a simple FET switch; it will have to be high side if you want your pi and supervisor MCU to be in communication.

Also remember that you must not apply I/O's voltages above a supply voltage, so if you are going to power down the pi, you need to first take any communication lines to it low.  That is not only a matter of being outside damage specifications, but also that I/O's driven into an unpowered IC will source current, ultimately resulting in power draw as the I/O tries and fails to re-power the unpowered chip through its protection diodes.

Ideally consider replacing the pi with an SoC designed for the mobile (rather than mains-powered set-top-box) market that as a result actually has meaningful power save modes.